# How can I track the last location of a shipment effeciently using latest date of reporting?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, query-performance

I need to find the latest location of each cargo item in a consignment. We mostly do this by looking at the route selected for a consignment and then finding the latest (max) time
entered against nodes of this route. For example if a route has 5 nodes and we have entered timings against first 3 nodes, then the latest timing (max time) will tell us its location among the 3 nodes.
I am really stuck on this query regarding performance issues. Even on few hundred rows, it takes more than 2 minutes. Please suggest how can I improve this query or any alternative approach I should acquire?

Note: ATA= Actual Time of Arrival and ATD = Actual Time of Departure

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       c.id   as cid
     , c.ref  as cons_ref 
     , c.Name
     , c.CustRef  
  FROM consignments c  
 INNER JOIN routes r        ON c.Route = r.ID   
 INNER JOIN routes_nodes rn ON rn.Route = r.ID   
 INNER JOIN cargo_timing ct ON c.ID=ct.ConsignmentID   
 INNER JOIN ( SELECT t.ConsignmentID, Max(t.firstata) as MaxDate 
                FROM cargo_timing t 
               GROUP BY t.ConsignmentID 
            ) as TMax   
         ON (    TMax.MaxDate=ct.firstata 
             AND TMax.ConsignmentID=c.ID  
            )
INNER JOIN nodes an         ON ct.routenodeid = an.ID    
INNER JOIN contract cor     ON cor.ID = c.Contract   
WHERE c.Type = 'Road' 
  AND ( c.ATD = 0 AND c.ATA != 0 )   
  AND (cor.contract_reference in  ('Generic','BP001','020-543-912'))   
ORDER BY c.ref ASC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you assign each node an ID and add that ID to the table `consignments` as a foreign key? That would allow you to set the "current" node when the cargo passes through a node. The time difference between now and the last update of the "current node" field in the `consignments` table would then give you an idea how for the cargo got on the route.

Comment: Aaron I appreciate your help, but there are few things making it difficult that way. First We need to dig down to location of each cargo item inside a whole consignment. Secondly this will require much changes in the already messed up code and that's why I am trying to avoid that. But I would be forced to do that as a last resort.

Comment: In that case, add another table which contains the info and contains foreign keys to the nodes of the route and the item you need to track. This should make it more simple to extend the existing data model and the code.